# Argument for proving that the universe must be indeterministic

Tags: quantum-interpretations, determinism, randomness

Can there exist an argument that could be used for proving that the universe is indeterministic?

If this one seems to be too strict (rigorous), I would also be interested to know a 1-sentence argument from either QEM or statistical mechanics that conjectures the indeterminism of the universe?

Sources:

1. I already received an answer, "QM wave function is interpreted as a probability density and statistical mechanics postulates equates the ensemble average with the time average of a given physical quantity." (http://www.quora.com/Is-there-an-argument-that-could-be-used-for-proving-that-the-universe-is-indeterministic), but I still fail to see the actual argument.
2. http://www.wired.com/2014/04/quantum-theory-flow-time/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63811/50583

Comment: ACuriousMind, I read this answer already. My question here is about finding whether there can exist such an argument for indeterminism.

Comment: I do not think you will find a 1-sentence argument, it is a little more complex than that. See for instance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell's_theorem

Comment: Mr Fernandez, I know Bell's theorem, but I cannot see how it can provide an argument that world must be indeterministic. 

I have many times heard that we know it for sure that it is such at microscopic level. How can we know that investigation at nano- or higher-resolution level cannot change our mind?

Namely, what is this argument, that you have in mind, based on?

Comment: Lets take a look at: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63811/is-the-universe-fundamentally-deterministic

There we have "Indeterminism in Quantum Mechanics is given by another "evolution" that the wavefunction may experience: wavefunction collapse. This is the source of indeterminism in Quantum Mechanics, and is a mechanism that is still not well understood at a fundamental level (this is often called as "Measurement Problem")."

If the wavefunction collapse is not yet understood, could be possible that we will need to change our minds if we understand it better?

Comment: Dear Tesgoe: perhaps you could fill in your background on your user profile - it may help people understand a bit more what your aims are and what background you already have. You speak of learning from Riemann and Gödel: do you have training (even self) in theoretical physics and to roughly what level?

Comment: Dear Rod Vance, it is computer science and mathematics. When I first started to think about this question, I thought about about it from a purely problem solving perspective.

Comment: I would put in the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle as a corner stone to indeterminancy. ( or the commutator maths in quantum mechanics). In physics there are no proofs. There are only conjectures and falsifications of conjectures. If the HUP is experimentally falsified, then we can talk again. At the moment it holds for all observations. The rest is mathematics, not physics, imo

Comment: Thank you Anna V., this is the sort of answer that I was looking for. I'd be happy to mark your insight as the answer.

Comment: Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle doesn't lead to indeterminism, wavefunction collapse does

Comment: agemO, thank you for your insight. Will dig deeper into both.

Comment: agemO, as for the wavefunction collapse, please take a look at the opinion of prof. Motl, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3158/why-quantum-entanglement-is-considered-to-be-active-link-between-particles/3163#3163

Answer (score 0):

one-liner

[coin flip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial), there you have it

another one:

The [time of radioactive decay of an atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat)

Explanation:

For a coin flip, there is **no (consistent) method** to predict the outcome, of course one can approximate in some cases, [but no method consistently gives the outcome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory).

Similarly in 2nd example, although quantum mechanics can predict cross-sections and mean values there is **no consistent method** to predict the time at which the next radio-active decay will happen. This can also be made more explicit via the [time-energy uncertainty relation $\Delta E \Delta \tau$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53802/what-is-delta-t-in-the-time-energy-uncertainty-principle/129960#129960) (note that *time* is also related to some parts of causality)

Comment: For the coin flip, proving that the long-run average does not exist is a rather nice exercise in probability theory.

Comment: @KyleKanos, what result do you refer exactly? sounds good

Comment: @KyleKanos, ahh i think i get it, you mean the sum of the random variables (either $0$ or $1$ or $-1$,  $1$), correct?

Comment: Looking back, I slightly confused myself here by misstating the issue. The long-run proportion of coin-flipping reveals the 50-50 deal (e.g., flipping 10, 100, 1000, ... coins will result in `# of Heads` $\simeq$ `# of Tails`). The existence of *one* preferred choice does not exist, as repeated use of Bayes' theorem returns $\mathbb{P}(H)=\mathbb{P}(T)$ for any particular throw.

Comment: @KyleKanos, ohh ok, i though you were referring to a divergent sum of random variables (if seen as an ordinary sum), i was confused too :)