# Is there anything random?

Tags: causality, determinism, randomness

Is there (in universe, wherever) anything random? Do we know any event (or whatever else) which has no reason? Of course there are some things that we cannot see, measure but it doesn't mean that they haven't a reason.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is the universe fundamentally deterministic?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63811/50583)

Comment: Do you know much about quantum mechanics?

Comment: Answer: sometimes

Comment: @Martin Heralecký It appears you are argumenting in similar ways that Einstein did when faced with the randomness of quantum mechanics whereas he proposed the so called hidden variable theory. This has since been refuted but it is an interesting discussion about the notion of a deterministic universe nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

> Do we know any event (or whatever else) which has no reason?

Reasons (causes) are constructions of human mind. There are many things that human mind has not been able to explain with reasons.

I like the following example my friend told me.

Imagine a man walking down the street that gets hit by a flowerpot falling down from a balcony above.

You may ask: what is the reason for the flowerpot to begin falling down from the balcony?

I can say: the wind has suddenly increased in intensity and it has puffed it off  (taken it down) from its unsecured place.

You think a little and then you ask: what is the reason for wind to puff off the flowerpot? I can say: there is no reason. Wind is notorious for being really hard to predict and it always behaves differently. It is not predictable. The reason stops right here.

(Of course, with enough data about the state of environment and massive computational capacity, it is possible to make predictions of future movements of air, so there is some additional reason. But the prediction is always inaccurate, so the reason is always imperfect and what is worse, such predictions gets less accurate with time. Quantitative weather forecasting gets the more unreliable the farther into future the prediction is made.)

Comment: Probably we cannot predict the wind but it is only because we don't have enough computing force and data. Nevertheless it doesn't mean it has no reason.

Comment: Granted, but if nobody has the data (that's very probable), what does it mean that "thing has a reason?" If there is to be a reason, there must be someone to think that reason - to do the reasoning.