# Is the universe immediately dependent upon the past?

Tags: time, determinism

Given complete knowledge of the precise state of every property of every particle and energy phenomenon existing in our universe for a given infinitely small frame of time, is it possible to completely determine the status of every property of every particle and energy phenomenon existing in the succeeding time frame?

This situation assumes that there are no restrictions towards the access of any information, particularly particle states, existing in the universe.

How can this situation be mathematically modeled?

Comment: This is what classical mechanics implies. Laplace thought about this deeply. http://cerebro.xu.edu/math/Sources/Laplace/

Comment: There are dozens of near-duplicates of this question accessible using the search bar...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will Determinism be ever possible?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7/)

Comment: For modelling have a look at dynamical chaos. It assumes the dynamics are known, second by second, long term individual particle predictability is lost though. New concepts emerge predicting ensemble behavior.http://serendip.brynmawr.edu/chaos/ , for examples. http://arxiv.org/abs/nlin/0107039

Comment: I would recommend not to close. Not many chaos connected questions have appeared and maybe somebody with background could write a good answer: that "no restrictions on information" do not lead to the dependence naively envisaged by the questioner.